# Vue components re-rendering on router push

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have created a global component that i share across multiple routes. i have simplified the component below for demonstration purposes.

```
#name area-wrapper
<template>
<div id="area">
    <div id="area-menu">
        <menu/>
    </div>
    <div id="area-content">
        <slot/>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Within the menu is a navbar which has options that will change the content of the `slot` which i could just turn into a `component v-bind:is` component.

What i have done is created several page for the routing

```
  pages
    _entity <--*** forgot to include this ***
      app
        index.vue
        _appId.vue
        new.vue
```

Each of these pages includes the component above and then adds in their own content for `id="area-content`

What i have been noticing is that the entire `area-wrapper` is being reloaded when i move from

- `website.com/app/112 (pages/app/_appId.vue)`
- `website.com/app/11 (pages/app/_appId.vue)`

I have noticed that if i move the `area-wrapper` to a layout then it works the problem is that the component will eventually be shared with several `apps` but will have a different `<menu/>` and layouts do not have `slots`

I'm not sure why vue is re-rendering the entire component even though it is shared among all the pages and is the same across each page.

What am i missing here?

If this is expected behavior my question becomes, how can i create a shared component that acts like a layout that i include in several pages without adjusting the `props` and have it not constantly reload

+==== UPDATE ====+

i have been trying to get nest routes to work because i believe this is what i am after. However `nuxt` is not generating them correctly

Per the documentation(``) i need to change my stucture to

```
  pages
    _entity
      messaging
        settings
          index.vue
        msg
          index.vue
        messaging.vue(wrong - changed back to index.vue) -> within here add the <nuxt-child> component 
      messaging.vue(need to move to _entity folder to create children)
```

`nuxt` should create the child components. However it is still continuing to create full routes. i am using `nuxt-i18n` will that cause a problem?

routes

```
...
{
  path: "/:entity/messaging/messaging",
  component: _8a865700,
  name: "entity-messaging-messaging___en"
}, {
  path: "/:entity/messaging/:msg?",
  component: _1ef926cc,
  name: "entity-messaging-msg___en"
}, {
  path: "/:entity/messaging/settings",
  component: _7b358e6a,
  name: "entity-messaging-settings___en"
}
```

Comment: You could add a `router-link` and treat website.com/app/112, website.com/app/xxx as sub-child of website.com/app/.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on a sub-child because than is pretty much the desired behavior

Comment: @Varun I got nested to work and that was the solution!!!!!!!!

Comment: great to hear that. If you facing any specific issues now, update the question and il take a look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I originally created the nested route within the folder.Instead, you need to put the parent page within the root of what directory the folder exists.

```
pages
 _entity
  messaging
    settings
      index.vue
    msg
      index.vue
    messaging.vue(wrong - changed back to index.vue) -> within here add the <nuxt-child> component 
  messaging.vue(need to move to _entity folder to create children)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define routing in your app as suggested [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html) (pure Vue) or [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/) (with vue-router). Without it you are reloading a whole page (and the app) when you change the URL.